# display from mysql database with web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I started to write a web service to display data from mysql database

I do not know what's the problem this wsdl. when I add a web reference in C #, an error is displayed

i use this wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- partie 1 : Definitions -->
<definitions      name="listeClient" 
    targetNamespace="urn:listeClient" 
    xmlns:typens="urn:listeClient" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <!-- partie 2 : Types-->
    <types>
        <xsd:schema       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            targetNamespace="urn:listeClient">
        </xsd:schema>
    </types> 


    <!-- partie 3 : Message -->
    <message name="rechercheResponse">
        <part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>

    <!-- partie 4 : Port Type -->
    <portType name="listeClientPort">
        <!-- partie 5 : Operation -->
        <operation name="recherche">
            <output message="typens:rechercheResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <!-- partie 6 : Binding -->
    <binding name="listeClientBinding" type="typens:listeClientPort">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="recherche">
            <soap:operation soapAction="listeClientPortAction"/>
            <output name="rechercheResponse">
                <soap:body        use="encoded"       
                    namespace="urn:listeClient" 
                    encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <!-- partie 7 : Service -->
    <service name="listeClientService">
        <documentation>Recherche de produit dans la base </documentation>
        <!-- partie 8 : Port -->
        <port name="listeClientPort" binding="typens:listeClientBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/check-net/test/Serveur/server.php"/> <!-- modifier ce chemin vers server.php -->
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

in the client side c #
it shows me the following error

```
Error 3 Error custom tool: Unable to import WebService / Schema. Unable to import binding 'listeClientBinding' from namespace 'urn: ClientList'. Operation 'search' on portType 'listeClientPort' from namespace 'urn:ClientList' has the following syntax error: The operation has no corresponding link. Check if the operation, input and output in the Binding section names correspond to the names of the PortType section.
```

php

```
<?php

// premiere etape : desactiver le cache lors de la phase de test
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

// on indique au serveur a quel fichier de description il est lie
$serveurSOAP = new SoapServer('clients.wsdl');

// ajouter la fonction RechercheProduit au serveur
$serveurSOAP->addFunction('recherche');
// lancer le serveur
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

{
        $serveurSOAP->handle();
}
else
{
        echo 'desole, je ne comprends pas les requetes GET, veuillez seulement utiliser POST';
}


    function connexion($server, $user, $pswr, $base)
    {
        mysql_connect($server, $user, $pswr);
        mysql_select_db($base);
    }

    function recherche()
{
connexion("localhost","root","","test");
$Rq="select Nomc,Prenomc,Adresse,codePostale from client";
$Resultat=mysql_query($Rq);
$XML="<clients>";
while($clt=mysql_fetch_array($Resultat)) 
$XML.="<client>
<Nomc>".$clt["Nomc"]."</Nomc>
<Prenomc>".$clt["Prenomc"]."</Prenomc>
<Adresse>".$clt["Adresse"]."</Adresse>
<codePostale>".$clt["codePostale"]."</codePostale>
</client>";
$XML.="</clients>";
echo $XML;
return($Resultat);
}

?>
```

Comment: How is this PHP or MySQL related?

Comment: I added the php code related

Comment: This question is making less and less sense as you add code. What problem are you trying to solve here? The PHP code has nothing to do with your WSDL problem.

Comment: My problem is with C #
when I add a web reference (wsdl) in c # to use the web service
it displays the error

Comment: That's fine. Don't just pile on unrelated code and confuse the issue. The PHP code you've added is not part of the problem.

Comment: so what's the solution